# C, 'fork: resource temporarily unavailable' on TCP server

Tags: c, fork, tcpserver

```
int
run ()
{
  char str[100];
  int listen_fd, comm_fd;

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  listen_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  bzero (&servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons (INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons (8080);
  int n;
  bind (listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  listen (listen_fd, 10);

  int pid;
  while (1)
    {
      comm_fd = accept (listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
      if (comm_fd < 0)
        printf ("ERROR on accept");
      //fork new process
      pid = fork ();
      if (pid < 0)
        {
          printf ("ERROR in new process creation");
        }
      if (pid == 0)
        {
          close (listen_fd);
          bzero (str, 256);
          n = read (comm_fd, str, 255);
          if (n < 0)
            printf ("ERROR reading from socket");
          printf ("Here is the message: %s\n", str);
          n = write (comm_fd, "I got your message", 18);
          if (n < 0)
            printf ("ERROR writing to socket");
          close (comm_fd);
        }
      else
        {

          close (comm_fd);
        }
    }

  printf ("readIn Exit!");
  exit (1);

}
```

Why does this make a fork bomb, and how can i get it to work as a multi-client server that can handle client loss?

Some posts suggested the max process per user being too low, yet mine is 709. to me that seems plenty for this piece to run (i'm using a mac book)

I have also tried the following method but with the same result:

```
while((comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL))){
         pid = fork();
         if(pid == 0){
            close(listen_fd);
            while(1){
              bzero( str, 100);
              read(comm_fd, str, 100);
              printf("S: %s", str);
              write(comm_fd, str, strlen(str)+1);
              sleep(1);
            }
           exit(1);
         } else {
           close(listen_fd);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Probably because your children processes do not break out of the `while(1)` loop and will eventually call fork() themselves.

Comment: Use `perror` on failure of `fork` (or most other syscalls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fork bomb because you never terminates the child, so it continues to run by looping in the while where `accept()` gives an error but doesn't terminates the process. So it continues to `fork()` and doing so forever.

Modify the code like this:

```
if (pid == 0)
  {
    close (listen_fd);
    bzero (str, 256);
    n = read (comm_fd, str, 255);
    if (n < 0)
      printf ("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf ("Here is the message: %s\n", str);
    n = write (comm_fd, "I got your message", 18);
    if (n < 0)
      printf ("ERROR writing to socket");
    close (comm_fd);
    exit(some_value); // terminates the child
  }
```

To clean the system tables, you also need to wait for children termination :

```
else
  {
    close (comm_fd);
    while (waitpid(0,NULL,WNOHANG)!=-1); // clean system tables non blocking
  }
```

This is not the best way to do the table but it is relatively efficient, at least sufficient. The best way is to catch signal `SIGCHLD` and clean the table in the handler.

Comment: That will still fill the process table with zombies. The second problem is the missing wait() call in the parent.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fork bomb because of this part:

```
while (1) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { /* child */
       ...read()...write()...
    } else {        /* parent */
       close(comm_fd);
    }
}
```

This is an infinite loop where the parent keeps forking and closing comm_fd. Each child, after a successful read and write, will in turn fork in the next iteration. Repeat until all process slots are leaked.

Your second snippet uses up all process slots because the parent needs to `wait()` or `wait4()` to collect the exit status of the children. A process remains in the zombie state until this is done. Each zombie occupies a process slot.

Like a malloc needs a corresponding free, a fork needs a wait.

PS: the canonical infinite loop in C is written `for(;;)` to avoid a constant-value boolean in `while(1)`.

Comment: yeah that was a little silly of me, please see the edit as my alternative approach had the same result.

Comment: @Simon. You never reap the exit status of the children with one of the wait() functions. This fills the process table with zombies.